# Maximum limit of Retweets on Twitter

Tags: twitter

Say if I retweeted everything in my Twitter stream, is there a limit per day that I would reach?

If so, should I untweet some of these posts to stay under the limit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on how many tweets you retweet and send then, yes.

You are limited to sending 1,000 updates per day broken down into semi-hourly intervals.  If you hit your account update limit, you will have to wait until you have passed the limit-period before you can send further updates.  Retweets are classed as an update.

You would also be limited by the [API Rate Limits](https://support.twitter.com/articles/160385) - currently 150 unauthenticated API calls and 350 authenticated API calls.

Other Account Limits are as follows:

- **Direct Messages:** 250 per day.
- **Updates:** 1,000 per day. The daily update limit is further broken down into smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals. Retweets are counted as updates.
- **Changes to Account Email:** 4 per hour.
- **Following (daily):** Please note that this is a technical account limit only, and there are additional rules prohibiting aggressive following behavior. You can find detailed page describing following limits and prohibited behavior on the [Follow Limits and Best Practices Page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/68916-following-rules-and-best-practices). The technical follow limit is 1,000 per day.
- **Following (account-based):** Once an account is following 2,000 other users, additional follow attempts are limited by account-specific ratios. The [Follow Limits and Best Practices Page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/68916-following-rules-and-best-practices) has more information.

Further information on Account limits (DM's, Updates, Following etc) can be found [here](https://support.twitter.com/entries/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following)